# Get data from remote server with ajax

Tags: jquery

Im using an exchange rate widget from widget.fx-exchange.com and its pretty working with php include command but the issue its radically affect the page load and Im thinking it will be possible through ajax-jquery get request.

```
   $.ajax({

     type: "get",
     url: "http://widget.fx-exchange.com/converter.php",
     data: "fg=en&ff=USD&ft=PHP,EUR,PKR,INR,AED,&fa=1&cb=F0F0F0&cc=000000&fy=3",
            success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#exrate").html(data);
            }

     });
```

TIA.

Comment: Is any data being alerted?

Comment: @Lance I'm getting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.  Not sure if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Okay, well upon success of the AJAX call, the div with the id of "extrate" should be populated with the data returned from the php file. Is it doing that?

Comment: There is no update at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your data string as follows

```
data: encodeURIComponent("fg=en&ff=USD&ft=PHP,EUR,PKR,INR,AED,&fa=1&cb=F0F0F0&cc=000000&fy=3"),
```

Comment: Hi, it did not work as well, I added the error block on ajax request and it return this error. http://imageshack.com/i/5np4xdp

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct ajax file in the head of your document? <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

Comment: I'm using a 1.7.2 library (local host file) but regardless of the library the error return the same.

Comment: The link (http://widget.fx-exchange.com/converter.php) that you're trying to send data to doesn't even work. It returns a 404 error upon trying to view it in my browser

Comment: I thought so that was the case but the its actually return data if access directly (eg http://widget.fx-exchange.com/converter.php?fg=en&ff=USD&ft=EUR,HKD,&fa=1&cb=F0F0F0&cc=000000&fy=3)

Answer (score 0):

For Cross Domain Ajax, you have to use JSONP - because this usually is forbidden ...

If you have no access to the remote host to provide JSONP, what about loading the contents via an simple PHP bridge? Use file_get_contents('contents from remote url') on your local host to provide a "local" source for your AJAX call.